# Rails 3. How to build a table from invoice's line items and the line item names vary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been breaking my head for almost two days now and I can't find a solution.

I have a table that lists invoices with invoice number, total, amount paid and balance; and it works well. Now I have to add all the line items to the table.

The invoices table has the columns: of_lax, air_rate_customer, pss, so that part it's easy, I just have to check if there is a value there.

**The tricky part** is for the `fcl_variable_cost_1_amount` attributes, I got 8 of those (fcl_variable_cost_1_amount, fcl_variable_cost_2_amount, etc).

The `fcl_variable_cost_1_amount` has a corresponding fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id that links to a Charge tables.

So in one invoice fcl_variable_cost_1_id might be 34 and amount $100 (id 34 corresponds to "ISF").

In another invoice fcl_variable_cost_1_id might be 12 and amount $50 (id 12 corresponds to "Examination fee").

**so how can I make the variable name line items appear in the column they should?**

This is my code. There is also a screenshot. [image]

```
<% headings = Hash.new %>
<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
<% unless shipment.invoice.nil? %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv.nil? %>
    <% headings['of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv'] = "Ocean Freight (FCL)" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.of_lax.nil? %>
    <% headings['of_lax'] = "Ocean Freight (LCL)" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.nil? %>
    <% headings['air_rate_customer'] = "Air Freight" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.pss.nil? %>
    <% headings['pss'] = "PSS" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.hc_lax.nil? %>
    <% headings['hc_lax'] = "HC LAX" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="9">Customer AR Statement for <%= @customer.company_name %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">MTY</th>
    <th>Shipper</th>
    <th>HBL</th>
    <th>Container</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Delivered Customer</th>
    <th>Invoice Date</th>
    <% headings.each_pair do |k,v|%>
      <th><%= v %></th>
    <% end %>
    <th>Invoice Total</th>
    <th>Amount Paid</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
  </tr>

<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><%= shipment.file_number %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.shipper.company_name %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.hbl %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.container %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.status %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.age %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.invoice.delivered_customer ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.invoice.read_issued_at unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <% if shipment.invoice.nil? %>
      <td colspan="<%= headings.count %>"></td>
    <% else %>
      <% headings.each_pair do |k,v| %>        
        <% if k == "of_lax" and !shipment.invoice.of_lax.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.lcl_of_customer_total %>
        <% elsif k == "of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv" and !shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv %></td>
        <% elsif k == "air_rate_customer" and !shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.volweight * shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.to_s.to_d) %></td>
        <% elsif k == "pss" and !shipment.invoice.pss.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.invoice.pss.to_s.to_d * shipment.volweight) %></td>
        <% elsif k == "hc_lax" and !shipment.invoice.hc_lax.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.invoice.hc_lax.to_s.to_d * shipment.volweight) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td></td>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_total unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_amount_paid unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_open_balance unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="<%= 7 + (headings.count) %>"></td>
    <th>Totals</th>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:overall] %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:paid] %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:balance] %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference in case anyone runs into a similar task

```
<% headings = Hash.new %>
<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
<% unless shipment.invoice.nil? %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv.nil? %>
    <% headings['of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv'] = "Ocean Freight (FCL)" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.of_lax.nil? %>
    <% headings['of_lax'] = "Ocean Freight (LCL)" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.nil? %>
    <% headings['air_rate_customer'] = "Air Freight" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.pss.nil? %>
    <% headings['pss'] = "PSS" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.hc_lax.nil? %>
    <% headings['hc_lax'] = "HC LAX" %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_amount.nil? %>
    <% headings[(Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_charge_id)).name] = Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_charge_id).name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="9">Customer AR Statement for <%= @customer.company_name %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">MTY</th>
    <th>Shipper</th>
    <th>HBL</th>
    <th>Container</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Delivered Customer</th>
    <th>Invoice Date</th>
    <% headings.each_pair do |k,v|%>
      <th><%= v %></th>
    <% end %>
    <th>Invoice Total</th>
    <th>Amount Paid</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
  </tr>

<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><%= shipment.file_number %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.shipper.company_name %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.hbl %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.container %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.status %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.age %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.invoice.delivered_customer ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td><%= shipment.invoice.read_issued_at unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <% if shipment.invoice.nil? %>
      <td colspan="<%= headings.count %>"></td>
    <% else %>

      <% headings.each_pair do |k,v| %>        
        <% if k == "of_lax" and !shipment.invoice.of_lax.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.lcl_of_customer_total %>
        <% elsif k == "of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv" and !shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.of_customer_amount_for_customer_inv %></td>
        <% elsif k == "air_rate_customer" and !shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.volweight * shipment.invoice.air_rate_customer.to_s.to_d) %></td>
        <% elsif k == "pss" and !shipment.invoice.pss.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.invoice.pss.to_s.to_d * shipment.volweight) %></td>
        <% elsif k == "hc_lax" and !shipment.invoice.hc_lax.nil? %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (shipment.invoice.hc_lax.to_s.to_d * shipment.volweight) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_1_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_2_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_3_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_4_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_5_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_6_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_7_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_amount.nil? %>
                <% if Charge.find(shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_charge_id).name == v %>
                  <%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.fcl_variable_cost_8_amount %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_total unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_amount_paid unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency shipment.invoice.customer_open_balance unless shipment.invoice.nil? %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="<%= 7 + (headings.count) %>"></td>
    <th>Totals</th>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:overall] %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:paid] %></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency @totals[:balance] %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```